# How to show text and img in button with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How to show text and img in button with CSS. This is the webpage http://lukatce.byethost4.com/
I have tried with

```
content: "Text";
```

And it didn't worked

I can't add span id and id neither right with input type ?
How could with css show or hide (display: none) value of button ?

This is HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
```

I want this becouse I want text in button for desktop and icon of mobile (responsive)

For img with css this code would be correct ? I can't get it work.

```
background-image: url(/img/icons/search.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
width: ;
height: ;
```

Comment: Input type=submit is notoriously difficult to work with, which is why I think you are having problems. Try swapping it out for a button element.

Comment: are you using jQuery with it? If yes then use <button> instead.

Comment: @pratiknagariya what does <button> element has to do with jQuery?

Comment: It works well enough **BUT** it will overide the basic styling of the 'button' removing border-radies etc. - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/84kZs/9/

Comment: we can use image or text inside <button> element. And form can be submitted using Jquery.

Comment: I am not sure if it is using jQuery I think it don't. Its done via "form action" and method "post"

I tried to add same HTML code just for mobile and renamed div etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using a span with a class for the text and an other one for the icon inside a button element and displaying them or not using the media queries?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. Do you maybe have some examples ?

All I want is not to show text in button for mobile (so disable it in css) and just add background img in css